# How can I access my Rooms database's Repository from a Worker class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-workmanager

I hava a `Worker` class in my application where I want to get the data from my Rooms database. Since I am using MVVM architecture, how can I get the data from the database using repository in my `Worker` class?

Code -

**Worker class**

```
public class SendNotification extends Worker {


    public SendNotification(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        String flightnumber = getInputData().getString("flight");
        String date = getInputData().getString("date");
       

        sendNotification(flightnumber,date);

        return Result.success();

    }}
```

**Repository**

```
public class FlightRepository {

    private FlightDao flightDao;
    private LiveData<List<Flight>> allFlights;

    public FlightRepository(Application application) {
        FlightDatabase database = FlightDatabase.getInstance(application);
        flightDao = database.flightDao();
        allFlights = flightDao.getAllFlights();

    }

    public void insert(Flight flight) {
        new InsertFlightAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(flight);
    }

    public void update(Flight flight) {
        new UpdateFlightAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(flight);
    }

    public void delete(Flight flight) {
        new DeleteFlightAsyncTask(flightDao).execute(flight);
    }

    public void deleteAllFlights() {
        new DeleteAllFlightsAsyncTask(flightDao).execute();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Flight>> getAllFlights() {
        return allFlights;
    }

    public Flight getFlight(String flightNumber, String date){
        return flightDao.getFlight(flightNumber,date);
    }

    public boolean existsFlight(String flightNumber, String date){
        return flightDao.existsFlight(flightNumber, date);

}
```

Comment: your woker class _depends_ on your repository, right? so then, make an instance of your repository and use it in your class

Comment: @a_local_nobody I need to pass in an Application parameter when initialising repository, however since here its a class and not an activity, how can i instantiate?

Comment: ah, i see. perhaps you'll have to change your constructor to make use of context and not application

Comment: @a_local_nobody I am using the Repository in my ViewModel and hence I need that constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create an instance of  `FlightRepository` inside the `Worker`:

```
public class SendNotification extends Worker {

  private FlightRepository flightRepo;


public SendNotification(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.flightRepo = new FlightRepository(context)
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    String flightnumber = getInputData().getString("flight");
    String date = getInputData().getString("date");
   
    // Do what is needed with flightRepo

    sendNotification(flightnumber,date);

    return Result.success();

}}
```

Making some assumptions here. I'd refactor `FlightDatabase` to accept a `Context`, rather than `Application`. I'm not sure why the database would need access to `Application`

Comment: Sometimes even when teh flightnumber and date have value in teh activity, it is shown to be null in the doWork() method of the worker. What can be the reason? Because I know for sure, flightnumber and date are never null

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the Activity code. I suggest trying to figure that out for yourself before posting another question. 

This page about setting the input data for a worker may help: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#params